# How do I redirect from an MVC Post Action back to the bootstrap popup modal partial view where the post came from?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, bootstrap-modal

How do I redirect from an MVC Post Action back to the bootstrap popup modal partial view where the post came from?

Here is the PartialView sitting in the Bootstrap modal popup on the page.
It has a div with a validation taghelper waiting for any model errors.

```
@model CreateRoleViewModel

<div class="panel panel-primary partialModalFormDivs">
    @Html.Partial("_ModalHeader",
        new ModalHeader
        {
            Heading = "ADD ROLE",
            glyphiconClass = "glyphicon glyphicon-random"
        }
    )

    <div class="panel-body">
        <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
        <form asp-action="CreateRole" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="RoleName"></label>
                <input asp-for="RoleName" class="form form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
               <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

It posts to this action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateRole(CreateRoleViewModel createRoleViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            IdentityRole role = new IdentityRole(createRoleViewModel.RoleName);

            IdentityResult result
                = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(role);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (IdentityError error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
                }
            }
        }
        return View(createRoleViewModel);
    }
```

I can return a PartialView like this at the end:

```
return View("_CreateRole", createRoleViewModel);
```

But then the whole page is cleared and this partial is returned with no layout file.

How can I return the results back to the modal popup window.
I understand the problem and the current behavior.  But has anyone else solved this?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is an ajax post and then just return a partial view and replace the form. The form should be inside a container div with an id that is used to replace its contents with the ajax post result. To do this you need to include the [jquery unobtrusive ajax](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive) script which will auto wire the ajax based on the data-* attributes on the form as shown below

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div id="resultcontainer">
        <form asp-action="CreateRole" method="post"
        data-ajax="true" 
        data-ajax-method="POST" 
        data-ajax-mode="replace" 
        data-ajax-update="#resultcontainer"
        >
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="RoleName"></label>
                <input asp-for="RoleName" class="form form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
               <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and don't forget to return a partial view

```
return PartialView(createRoleViewModel);
```

Comment: No, that won't work.  If it is successful then it should go back to the full index page.  If there is an error I want to show the model errors in the modal popup on the index page.

Comment: it will work but you need to put the form itself in another partial view that is referenced from the main view then the post method returns only that partial replacing only the form. A redirect inside a modal could only work with an iframe, an ajax solution will work and does not need an iframe